# Jupyter NoteBook: draw a graph on the Notebook instead of save the file to the disk

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have the following code:

[image]

Is it possible to print the graph just inside the Notebook instead of saving as a file? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to plot the plots inline inside your jupiter-notebook:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

[image: Plotting inline in the notebook]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `matplotlib`:

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 nx.draw(G)
 plt.show()
```

[source](http://www.python-course.eu/networkx.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use draw in the following manner :

```
draw(G, show='ipynb')
```

If you want all graphs to be drawn inline, then you can set a global parameter.

```
from nxpd import nxpdParams
nxpdParams['show'] = 'ipynb'
draw(G)
```

But im not sure this will work with Jupyter, this will work for ipython though.